# Access query data type conversion

Tags: sql, ms-access, type-conversion

I'm trying to create a table from an existing table. I want the new column to be a percentage column with data type "Number". The code below changes column data type to "Text". I tried to use `Format(num,"Percent")`, it does the same.

```sql
SELECT 
    Format([DB].[Number1]/DB.[Number2],"0.00%") AS [New Column Name]
INTO newTable
FROM [OldTable] as DB;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the query to store the raw quotients and adjust the field's *Format* property afterward.

```sql
SELECT 
    ([DB].[Number1] / DB.[Number2]) AS [New Column Name]
INTO newTable
FROM [OldTable] as DB;
```

You can open the table in Design View and choose *"Percent"* for the field's *Format*.  If you want to do the same thing with VBA, I tested this in Access 2010:

```vb
Dim db As DAO.Database
Set db = CurrentDb
With db.TableDefs("newTable").Fields("New Column Name")
    .Properties.Append .CreateProperty("Format", dbText, "Percent")
End With
```

Another way to approach this would be to create the table, set the field format, and then use an "append query" (instead of a "make table query") to load your data into the table.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the "%", it forces the result to include it, which can only be stored in text type field.

```
SELECT 

Format([DB].[Number1]/DB.[Number2],"0.00") AS [New Column Name]

INTO newTable

FROM [OldTable] as DB;
```

to get a percentage multiply the value by 100

```
SELECT 

Format(([DB].[Number1]/DB.[Number2])*100,"0.00") AS [New Column Name]

INTO newTable

FROM [OldTable] as DB;
```